# How to observe in ClassB if an object is created in ClassA?

Tags: swift, swift3, key-value-observing

My Object:

```
//Object to observe
struct Text {
    let savedUserHeader: String
    let savedUserText: String
}
```

`ClassA` where I create the object:

```
//First Class 
class A {
   func somefunc(){
      let a = Text(savedUserHeader: "testHeader", savedUserText: "testText")
    }
}
```

In `classB`, I want to observe if a new object was created:

```
//Second Class
class B {
  var text: Text? {
      didSet{
        headerlabel.text = text.savedUserHeader
        saveUserLabel.text = text?.savedUserText
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `a` is really a variable local to `somefunc()`?

Comment: You should reconsider your architecture if this is how you're displaying text to the user. You would most likely want to explicitly write in code something like `instanceOfB.text = instanceOfText` and do as you already are doing in `didSet`. By listening for moments of when instances of `Text` are created, you will have almost no idea where your UI bugs will come from, especially if `Text` instances can be made from multiple threads and simultaneously. By explicitly writing it as I am suggesting, you can put a breakpoint on it and dig through just the main thread's stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delegate**

You can use the Delegate pattern to observe, let create a protocol called `ADelegate`:

```
protocol ADelegate {
    func didCreateText(text: Text)
}
```

Then, add a variable called `delegate` in the class A and pass a `Text` object into `didCreateText(text:)` method in the `somefunc()`:

```
//First Class
class A {

    var delegate: ADelegate?

    func somefunc(){
        let a = Text(savedUserHeader: "testHeader", savedUserText: "testText")
        delegate?.didCreateText(text: a)
    }
}
```

Next, when you create an object A in B, set `a.delegate = self` and implement `ADelegate` protocol:

```
//Second Class
class B: ADelegate {

    var headerlabel: UILabel!
    var saveUserLabel: UILabel!

    var a = A()

    var text: Text? {
        didSet{
            headerlabel.text = text?.savedUserHeader
            saveUserLabel.text = text?.savedUserText
        }
    }

    init() {
        a.delegate = self
    }

    func didCreateText(text: Text) {
        print("savedUserHeader: \(text.savedUserHeader)")
        print("savedUserText: \(text.savedUserText)")
    }
}
```

That's it! The method `didCreateText(text:)` will be called when an object `Text` is created in the `somefunc()` method:

```
let b = B()
b.a.somefunc()
```

**Notification Center**

Another solution is NotificationCenter. Let post a notification when create a `Text` object:

```
func somefunc(){
    let a = Text(savedUserHeader: "testHeader", savedUserText: "testText")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("addText"), object: a)
}
```

And observe in the class B:

```
init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observeText(noti:)), name: Notification.Name("addText"), object: nil)
}

@objc func observeText(noti: Notification) {
    if let text = noti.object as? Text {
        print("savedUserHeader: \(text.savedUserHeader)")
        print("savedUserText: \(text.savedUserText)")
    }
}
```

Let test it:

```
let b = B()
let a = A()
a.somefunc()
```

You will see the result:

```
savedUserHeader: testHeader
savedUserText: testText
```

Comment: Although this might be a solution, I believe that using delegation for such a case is not the best choice.

Comment: What about Notification solution?

Comment: @DanhHuynh I tried both and both worked, Thank you very much. The one with notifications seemed more natural because the one with the protocol hat this unfamiliar "b.a.somefunc" call. Interesting would be to know which way is more safe or the preferred way for Observing. Thanks again, helped me a lot :)